# MultipartUploadRequest me da error en algunos dispositivos

Tags: php, android-studio, libreria, subida-de-archivos

Tengo una aplicación que sube una imagen a mi servidor. Funciona bien con muchos dispositivos, pero en otros me da un error:

> java.net.ssl.SSL Handshake Exception:java
> security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
> certification path not found.

He consultado y la explicación que encuentro siempre hablan de error en el servidor, pero no lo entiendo. Si no altero nada y lo pruebo con otro dispositivo y funciona perfectamente. El código php funciona también bien.
Gracias por la atención.

Os paso el codigo:

```
  try {
        String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        new MultipartUploadRequest(getBaseContext(), uploadId, URL_SUBIRPICTURE)
                .addFileToUpload(fileQr.getPath(), "picture")
                .addParameter("filename", fileQr.getName())
                .addParameter("anfitrion", anfitrion)
                .addParameter("evento", event)
                .setMaxRetries(2)
                .setDelegate(new UploadStatusDelegate() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(UploadInfo uploadInfo, Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IError en la subida."+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(UploadInfo uploadInfo, ServerResponse serverResponse) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Imagen subida exitosamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(UploadInfo uploadInfo) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Imagen Cancelada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .startUpload();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage() + " " + exc.getLocalizedMessage());
        String miError ="IError en la subida."+ exc.getMessage() + " " + exc.getLocalizedMessage();
        //mTexNombre.setText(miError);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IError en la subida."+ exc.getMessage() + " " + exc.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si esto sucede el algunos dispositivos, me parece que el problema es que si tu app esta orientada a API 28, no se estan permitiendo conexiones no seguras, solo se van a permitir para tu aplicación conexiones seguras https://, para que esto no sea impedimento, puedes activar el soporte "ClearText" , definiendo dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml que se permitan este tipo de conexiones no cifradas usando:

```
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<application
    android:name="com.jorgesys.tracer.MyApplicationContext"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name_gr"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```